# Binding events programmatically (SyntheticEvent)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a container with multiple `input` boxes (with different properties). I'd like to alter the keydown behaviors for all of them. I am wondering whether there is a better way than to manually put `onKeyDown={this.handleKeydown}` property on every `<input>`.

Since ReactJS has it's own [`SyntheticEvent`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html) system, I don't want to bind normal javascript events which may interfere with the ReactJS's event system.

Is this possible with React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options come to mind

1. You could use an object and [jsx spread attributes](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html)

   ```
   var props = {onKeyDown: this.handleKeyDown};
   return (
     <input {...props} name="foo" />
     <input {...props} name="bar" />
     <input {...props} name="qux" />
   );
   ```
2. You could create a custom component

   ```
   var MyInput = React.createClass({
     handleKeyDown: function() {
       // ...
     },
     render: function() {
       return (
         <input onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} />
       );
     }
   });
   ```

   Then use it like this in another component

   ```
   render: function() {
     return (
       <MyInput name="foo" />
       <MyInput name="bar" />
       <MyInput name="qux" />
     );
   }
   ```

Comment: Both solutions look great! Thanks I didn't know about option 1!

Comment: @jtcwang happy to help. I just linked the appropriate docs too.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to put `onKeyDown={this.handleKeydown}` on the component which contains all the `<input>`s, but its suitability depends on what else is in the same container (other inputs and focusable elements).

Comment: In my case, I have custom elements in the same container as the `<input>`s so probably not the best idea. I think this may work but then you're 'leaking' the behavior of the component (and requires the caller to explictly allow that behavior). After some thought I think the best solution is to mix JSX and actual ReactJS javascript calls, which I completely forgot about.